# Remove text Decoration with react monaco editor

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend, monaco-editor

Hello I'm working with monaco editor on react and I highlight some part of my text thanks to the deltaDecorations

```
const editor = monacoEditorRef.current;
      const model = editor.getModel();

      if (model) {
        const matchList = findSub(overlap, model.getValue());

        const decorations = matchList.flatMap(match => {
          const matches = model.findMatches(match);
          const decorationOptions = {
            isWholeLine: false,
            className: 'highlighted-text',
          };

          return matches.map(match => ({
            range: match.range,
            options: decorationOptions,
          }));
        });

        editor.deltaDecorations([], decorations);
        editor.layout();
        monacoEditorRef.current = editor
      }
```

But when I try to remove this text decoration to get my original text back, the text still get the decoration.

```
  function Reset(){
    console.log("reset")
    const editor = monacoEditorRef.current;
    const existingDecorations = editor.getModel().getAllDecorations();
    const decorations = editor.deltaDecorations(existingDecorations, []);
    editor.layout();
  }
```

Is there a way to remove those decoration correctly ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Instead of using editor.getModel().getAllDecorations() to get all decorations, you can use the decorationsRef.current that you've previously stored when applying decorations. This way, you can keep track of the decorations you added and later remove them.

Comment: Yes it is actually working thank you